# load maps instead of scenes Blender GE

Tags: game-engine

i'm creating a fps game and i was wondering, which is the best way to load a new map without put the player manually in this map? everytime i'll have to create a scene and put my player in there? there isn't a way to creat a blend file for each map and make the main scene load it putting the player automatically in this map?

Sorry about my bad english

Comment: Don't you think that the scene the best place to place your player in? How should the BGE know where to place the player object, or even know what it is? Btw. you do no need to copy the player. You can link it. You can even link from other blend files.